# Can't uninstall old android sdk build tools and NDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have old versions of the android sdk build tools and the NDK I can't remove. When I try to uninstall them, the IDE replies that the "requested actions did not complete successfully. See the IDE log for details".
The log detail is below. It is of no help to me. Does anyone know how I could safely remove these old versions?

The log :

> 2022-10-01 19:26:29,665 [ 623305]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Packages to uninstall:
> 2022-10-01 19:26:29,665 [ 623305]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - NDK (Side by side) 24.0.8215888 (ndk;24.0.8215888)
> 2022-10-01 19:26:29,681 [ 623321]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - NDK (Side by side) 25.0.8775105 (ndk;25.0.8775105)
> 2022-10-01 19:26:29,695 [ 623335]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger -

2022-10-01 19:26:29,714 [ 623354]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Uninstall NDK (Side by side) 24.0.8215888 (revision: 24.0.8215888)".
2022-10-01 19:26:29,715 [ 623355]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Uninstall NDK (Side by side) 24.0.8215888 (revision: 24.0.8215888)" failed.
2022-10-01 19:26:29,715 [ 623355]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Uninstall NDK (Side by side) 25.0.8775105 (revision: 25.0.8775105)".
2022-10-01 19:26:29,715 [ 623355]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Uninstall NDK (Side by side) 25.0.8775105 (revision: 25.0.8775105)" failed.
2022-10-01 19:26:29,716 [ 623356]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages:
2022-10-01 19:26:29,716 [ 623356]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - NDK (Side by side) 24.0.8215888 (ndk;24.0.8215888)
2022-10-01 19:26:29,716 [ 623356]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - NDK (Side by side) 25.0.8775105 (ndk;25.0.8775105)
2022-10-01 19:28:06,382 [ 720022]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,384 [ 720024]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,385 [ 720025]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,386 [ 720026]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,387 [ 720027]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,389 [ 720029]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,390 [ 720030]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,391 [ 720031]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,391 [ 720031]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\24.0.8215888\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,392 [ 720032]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.0.8775105\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,394 [ 720034]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,395 [ 720035]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,396 [ 720036]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,397 [ 720037]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,398 [ 720038]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,399 [ 720039]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,400 [ 720040]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-31\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,402 [ 720042]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-32\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,403 [ 720043]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-32\google_apis\x86_64\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:06,404 [ 720044]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
2022-10-01 19:28:07,798 [ 721438]   WARN - tions.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel - auto-dispose 'Android SDK' id=AndroidSdkUpdater
2022-10-01 19:28:07,798 [ 721438]   WARN - tions.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel - auto-dispose 'Android SDK' id=AndroidSdkUpdater
2022-10-01 19:28:07,798 [ 721438]   WARN - tions.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel - auto-dispose 'Android SDK' id=AndroidSdkUpdater
2022-10-01 19:28:10,016 [ 723656]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

If you can not resolve to uninstall sdk parts from your IDE, **use the force**.

- Go to `Android Studio > Preferences > Android SDK > Android SDK Location`
- Verify sdk path is `C:\Users\glpbl_4vvog3j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` in your case
- Close Android Studio
- Backup Sdk folder if you want
- Delete Sdk folder, or rename it
- Open Android Studio
- Go to dialog at step 1. Click `Edit` to download and install a fresh SDK.
- Install all packages, tools... you need